# .htaccess make folder act as root?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

Is there a way to make .htaccess tell a folder to act as the lowest level? What I mean is this, say you have a folder like so:

```
/about/
/contact/
/css/
/images/
.htaccess
index.php
header.php
```

If they are at `/contact/index.php`, then if I have `<a href="../index.php">Home</a>` to go to the home page, it works all fine, but if they are on the actual main page, it will try to go a directory lower.

The reason is because Im trying to test sites in sub-folders.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by "then if I have Home to go to the home page"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directly answer your question, the answer is *no*. By the time, .htaccess is read, the path was already translated to a directory.

If you want to change the root, you have to do it in `httpd.conf` (or rewrite all the requests in the root to the destination directory). If you want to have several roots (under different domains), you have to use virtual hosts (again, only in `httpd.conf`).

You can also make your site work when it's not in the root directory.

- Use relative paths correctly ("../index.php" in "/contact/index.php" and "index.php" in the root webpages). Not a great option.
- Use absolute paths, but prefix them with the path of the website relative to the server root. The most fool-proof way to do this setting a constant for this in a file that you include in all your scripts.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky... but you could create the /home folder and put a duplicate copy of your index.php in there. Again, it is a total hack, but it should resolve what you are trying to do.

Another thing to consider is using mod_rewrite in the .htaccess to look for /home and route to the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

On /contact/index.php you can link to main index.php by using

```
<a href="/index.php">Link</a>
```

Comment: It wasn't super-clear from the question, but the reason he can't do that because he's testing the site in a subdirectory, meaning the target for the link would have to be "/subdir/index.php" (which wouldn't match the production environment).

Comment: So use a variable defined as siteRoot = "/subdir/"; and then any link or reference you use that.