# PHP a path beginning with / uses the root of the linux box it's hosted on. How to make / refer to the site root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web

This would make including files a lot easier. Is there anyway of doing this, for instance in a .htaccess file?

Comment: It's a viscous circle, I'm new to web design, and I googled how to do this before I tried, and everywhere only mentioned one thing .htaccess. Now people googling for it will find this post and use .htaccess as a buzzword too.

Comment: none of these are what you're looking for? [SO1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522787/htaccess-make-folder-act-as-root) [SO2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792153/changing-the-root-folder-via-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

PHP will reference files from where the file is located are like you have stated, and PHP is typically not aware of the URL that it is working with. I would recommend using spl_autoloader (http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) so that you only have to include one file and then spl_autoloader will include the rest of your classes.

Also look at:https://github.com/theseer/Autoload